# HyperLink Style is not working using set_column in xlsxwriter python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, xlsxwriter

I am using python xlsxwriter library to create excel. I need to apply background color to the cell for that I am using set_column method. All columns getting backgroundcolor except the column containing hyperlink. I tried various ways i can try with but not able to found anything. Cell format is working with write_rows but not with set_column containing hyperlink. Can anybody please help.

Sample Code:

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('hello.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

cell_format = workbook.add_format()

cell_format.set_bg_color('green')

worksheet.write('A1', 'https://google.com')
worksheet.set_column(0, 0, None, cell_format)

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

All columns have green color except having url.

Comment: The url format is overriding the column format. What do you want the output to be: green background with a blue url link or just a green background and no hyperlink?

Comment: @jmcnamara I want green background with hyperlink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution for this. There is parameter strings_to_urls which will consider url as string and then bgcolor will get applied.

```
workbook = Workbook(filename, {'strings_to_urls': False})
```

We can use this and then we will get bgcolor applied to url as well but it will no more be hyperlink.